# frame doesn't work in gwt app

Tags: gwt, frame

i have gwt app, and one of the 'page'(or display) has a iframe whose url point to google web page, however when deploy the app, google page doesn't show up. here is the code

```
  <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.ctntBox}">
      <div id="contactForm"> 
        <g:Frame url="http://www.google.com/"></g:Frame>
    </div></g:HTMLPanel>
```

if i replace the google webpage with a static image stored locally, it show up fine:

```
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.ctntBox}">
      <div id="contactForm">
        <g:Image url="img/myImg.jpg"></g:Image>
    </div>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
```

can anyone tell me why it won't work with external link? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Answered on the GWT group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/nwlTBBVGJSA/pho1SVeviQEJ

Copied here for convenience:

> Google refuses to be displayed in a frame using the X-Frame-Options HTTP header.
>   See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7055

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided creates the UI, including the frame, just fine. The thing you're *not* doing is setting a height and width for your frame, so it's effectively invisible. Change your code to the following and you'll see your frame.

```
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.ctntBox}">
  <div id="contactForm"> 
    <g:Frame url="http://www.google.com/" height="150px" width="150px" />
</div></g:HTMLPanel>
```

The reason you didn't have to specify the height and width for an image is because they are implicitly defined by the image itself. There's no way for GWT to know how big you want an iframe to render on your page, so you have to explicitly set the size.